# create application without any theme

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Hi I am new to Vaadin and I was looking about the theme.
In Vaadin, is it possible to to develop application without any theme?
I will apply theme only if any theming is required. So that it should look
normal html components.Currently I am using vaadin7 and I know how to customize
themes to the components which I dont need. I need to develop the applications without having any themes.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "empty" theme and use this one. (Means, one which does not inherit from any other theme)

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html

But be aware that the themes also influence the way the vaadin buttons are drawn, scroll behaviour of panels, and many many other things.

To prevent breaking basic stuff, there exists a base theme which only holds the minimal css/sass rules for vaadin.

Look in section 8.4.4. Built-in Themes
of https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html